# Problem with narrow renderplotly plots in R shiny when switching between tabs

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a question regarding some plotly outputs in R shiny. Please find a snippet of my ui.R code:

```
tabItem(tabName = "Main",
        column(width = 2,
               
               ## File Browser -------------------
               wellPanel(width = NULL, 
                         title = "File Browser",
                         fileInput(inputId = "fileName",
                                   "Choose file")
               ),

        # Box with plots ================
        column(width = 10,
               tabBox(width = NULL,
                      height = 1000,
                      
                      # Tab 1
                      tabPanel(title = "Tab 1",
                               
                               ### Plot 1 ----------------         
                               column(width = 12,
                                      box(width = NULL,
                                          solidHeader = TRUE,
                                          plotlyOutput("plot1", height = 500)
),
                                         
                      
                      ### Tab 2 ----------------
                      tabPanel(title = "Tab 2",
                               
                               #### Plot 2.1 ----------------
                               column(width = 6,
                                      box(
                                        width = NULL, 
                                        solidHeader = TRUE,
                                        title = "Plot 2.1",
                                        plotlyOutput("plot2.1", height = 500))),
                                        
                                        
                               #### Plot 2.2 ----------------
                               column(
                                 width = 6,
                                 
                                 box(width = NULL,
                                     solidHeader = TRUE,
                                     
                                     title = "Plot 2.2",
                                     plotlyOutput("plot2.2", height = 500)                                     
                                      
                                     )
                                 )
                               )
                      )
               )
        )
)
```

All plots are based on outputs of fileInput. When I upload a file into Shiny and I am currently looking at Tab 1, the plot is visualised properly in this tab. However, when I switch to the second tab, plots 2.1 and 2.2 are very narrow, without chaning the file. The other way around is also true, when I upload a file and I am currently looking at Tab 2, the plots are showed properly. When I change to Tab 1 again, the plot is really narrow. See this image below:

[Example narrow plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGZro.png)

How is this possible? Do I need to specificy other properties in the UI? Or is it something to do with that it is a plotly instead of plot?

Comment: It appears that you are not closing the `column()` properly.  You have a column of width 2 containing a column of width 10 which contains column of width 12, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Is this the cause of the narrow plots? Or is this just a comment in general?

Comment: This is the cause. Your `column(2,...)` is giving you the narrow plot.  Try 8 or 12 instead of 2.